# In WCF how do I access the user the service is running as?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS and want to gain access to the user the service runs as - not the caller. Is this possible?

I know about the aspNetCompatibilityEnabled, but that gives me the user calling the service, not the user the service is running under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [System.Environment.UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx)?